# How to draw part of space between two circles in Android

Tags: android, drawing

I would like to draw in Android something like shape in the picture. I have used `Path.drawArc` but I can't draw two arcs which are parts of cirlces with the same center. Another problem is how to draw two lines which connect these arcs. In iOS I would use `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`

How to draw shape like in the sketch?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is simple example using canvas and bitmaps, try this example and get some idea for your requirement.  [image cropping and transparent](http://android.okhelp.cz/drawbitmap-clippath-union-difference-intersect-replace-xor-android-example/)

Comment: This solution works great. I have another question: how to check if point is inside this shape. I am using circle equation and I'm checking that point is in bigger circle but not in smaller one. Nextly I'm computing angle to X axis where start of coordinate system is in place of circles' center. This works but I wonder is there better way?

Comment: Yes, it is tha way to check the point which is in side of 2circles, maintain the boundarys ani validate it., it works great.